# Step Function is only progressing by concurrency 57 and i need 300

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions, serverless-framework-step-functions

I already set the MaxConcurrency to 300 but when i start it still execution the MaxConcurrency as 57, how can i change it? How the Step function decide the MaxConcurrency?

JSON from Step Function:

```
{
  "Comment": "Get data from S3, clean and send to RDS",
  "StartAt": "Create-Instances",
  "States": {
    "Create-Instances": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource":"arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:****",
      "Next": "Filter-Data"
    },
    "Filter-Data": {
      "Type": "Map",
      "ItemsPath": "$.body",
      "MaxConcurrency": 300,
      "Iterator": {
        "StartAt": "Validate",
        "States": {
          "Validate": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "InputPath": "$",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:****",
            "OutputPath": "$",
            "End": true
          }
        }
      },
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you know the MaxConcurrency is still 57?

Comment: Also, from the question, it _seems_ like you want _at least_ 300 concurrency. That's not how MaxConcurrency works. MaxConcurrency = 300 does not mean you will get 300 parallel invocations, it means AWS Step Functions will guarantee it won't go _over_ 300 parallel invocations. AWS Step Functions decides how many concurrent invocations. From my anecdotal experience, the service usually gives you around 50.

Comment: @tankthinks but can i change this somehow?

Comment: No: you cannot specify "please execute with _at least_ N parallel executions"

Comment: Ok, Thank you :)